# Asset verification failed when creating xcode archive

Tags: flutter, xcode, onesignal

I encountered the following problems when trying to send an archive created in Xcode via a transporter. Unfortunately, I did not find a solution to these problems (the answers were not very detailed), so if you know a solution, please describe it in as much detail as possible, thank you very much in advance!

> 1)Asset validation failed CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more
> than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value 'com.atlas.almaz'
> under the iOS application 'Runner.app'. (ID:
> 52b4c9ca-b0cf-432b-b112-51a2d228270e)
>
> 2)Asset validation failed Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier
> 'com.atlas.almaz' of the application extension
> Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex should
> start with the application's bundle identifier 'com.atlas.almaz' and
> not contain more than one period “.” after the application's bundle
> ID. (ID: 61842dee-99e3-4b65-999b-e782c73179a0)

These are two similar problems, so I decided to create one question.

From the details -
Xcode - 14.3

my info.plist -

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Handyman Service User</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
```

ps: I tried to specify the bundle ID, but it didn’t help

Screenshot with basic settings -
[image: settings]

OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/General
[image: onesignal]

OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Signing&Capabilities

[image: onesignal]

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

PS: If this is important, then my application is written in flutter